# How can I install the HEDA SALESFORCE package in a scratch org?

Tags: salesforce

How can I install the HEDA SALESFORCE package in a scratch org? how do I get the package ID?

Answer (score 0):

1. With the repo https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/HEDAP.git
2. sfdx force:package:install -p 04t1R000001ID2OQAW -u